# php session serialization

Tags: php, session, serialization

I have one server with php5.3 + nginx + php-fpm and second server with php5.3 + apache2.
On both server in php.ini - session.serialize_handler = php.
And on first server session is serializing like this:

```
onlineuser|a:2:{s:4:"user";O:8:"stdClass":81:{s:12:"category_ids";s:1:"2";s:2:"id";i:114756;s:5:"utype";i:2;s:6:"passwd";s:32:"...";.......}
```

And on second server session is serializing like this:

```
kP_xItrmVGDX_QFX-49QcYMf0nfnkEZrLSCLhypvPais0DkcFol7zblcQv_U2ET8X_ygrBglUuSGtH9T87nnE-5Nge3sFE0hdF6ZzO1Ba8mu12DAil5a18EPZAW3sb5tEELqaQK5ByGkomONxGUjmdSFkph4pMZR_2Dkg714SK7Wdh5ZZacdiZrGUXt4...............
```

It's look like serialization methods are different.
Please advice how found out reason of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have Suhosin PHP extension installed at 2nd server.
If yes, set the parameter "suhosin.session.encrypt" to "Off" in it's php.ini

Answer (score 1):

I would check the [PHP v5 Changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php), specifically I see:

- v5.3.3

  - Fixed possible buffer overflows when handling error packets in mysqlnd. Reported by Stefan Esser. (Andrey)
- v5.2.14

  - Fixed handling of session variable serialization on certain prefix characters. Reported by Stefan Esser (Ilia)

*Gut instinct says it's the PHP engine, not the server it's hosted on, though it could also have to do with which binar(y/ies) and/or flags are loaded with the specific instance of PHP.*

Are you working directly with the serialized data (which is why you're concerned with method)? I'm a little curious as to why if you are.

Comment: I am doing load balancing and save session in redis then i need one session for two servers. But serialization methods are different and data of session is lost. I have on first server php 5.3.3 and on second php 5.3.8

Comment: I understand that maybe on second server php started with flags and session serialization to binary. It's right?